# 403 and 404 error on AJAX with code that has worked elsewhere

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have no idea what the issue could be with this code... because I have it working on another site I created. The idea is simple. Add an event listener on a button, then when it is pressed, the user is asked if they really want to delete the row, then AJAX POSTs that data to my server, which does the rest of the heavy lifting. But, when I press delete I'm getting a 403 error *and* what is weirder, up in the url bar, I'm seeing what looks like an HTML 4.01 page, and it says in the following in the URL bar:

```
The link on the
<a href="http://localhost/afton/index.php%3faction=home">referring
page</a> seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of
<a href="http://localhost/afton/index.php%3faction=home">that page</a>
```

Even though, if you put that into the browser bar, it gets to it just fine. Here is my AJAX/JavaScript code:

```
var delBut = table.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < delBut.length; i++) {
    var but = delBut[i];
    but.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var really = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry? This cannot be undone.");
        if (really) {
            var table = but.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input").location.value.charAt(0);
            switch(table){
                case 'h': table = "logins"; break;
                case 'n': table = "network"; break;
                case 'p': table = "passwords"; break;
            }
        var ID = but.parentElement.parentElement.id
        var loc = but.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input").location.value;
        console.log(table, ID, loc);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("post", "../internalPages/index.php?action=deleteEntry", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send('table=' + encodeURIComponent(table) + '&ID=' + encodeURIComponent(ID) + '&loc=' + encodeURIComponent(loc));
        ajax.onload = function() {
            window.location = ajax.responseText.trim();
        }
    }
    }, false);
}
```

By the way, I've `console.log`ed the variables and they are all getting captured correctly. And here is the PHP code:

```
case "deleteEntry":
    $location = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "loc", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $ID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "ID", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $table = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "table", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (empty($ID) || empty($table)){
        $message = "<p class='badMessage'>There was an application error. Please try again.</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        if ($location !== "home"){
            echo "/afton/internalPages/index.php?action=$location";
        } else {
            echo "/afton/index.php?action=$location";
        }
        exit;
    } switch($table) {
        case "passwords": $table = "passwords"; break;
        case "network": $table = "network"; break;
        case "logins": $table = "logins"; break;
        default:
            $message = "<p class='badMessage'>There was an application error. Please refresh the page and try again.</p>";
            $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        if ($location !== "home"){
            echo "/afton/internalPages/index.php?action=$location";
        } else {
            echo "/afton/index.php?action=$location";
        }
        exit;
        break;
    }
    $result = deleteEntry($ID, $table);
    if ($result === 1) {
        $message = "<p class='goodMessage'>The entry was successfully deleted from the database</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        if ($location !== "home"){
            echo "/afton/internalPages/index.php?action=$location";
        } else {
            echo "/afton/index.php?action=$location";
        }
        exit;
    } else {
        $message = "<p class='badMessage'>Nothing was deleted from the database</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        if ($location !== "home"){
            echo "/afton/internalPages/index.php?action=$location";
        } else {
            echo "/afton/index.php?action = $location";
        }
        exit;            
    }
break;
```

Comment: well is the relative path correct?

Comment: @epascarello yes, the user would be in a view when clicking that button, so they would go back one directory, then into the internalPages directory, then to the controller inside that directory

Comment: What's the url on which this code will work? What's url of backend endpoint?

Comment: @AdamMcGurk That's not how URL's work. HTTP server have **all** the power to rewrite urls, so You can not assume they map to directory structure. App itself can pretty much redirect urls as it likes too.

Comment: have you tried to add the full url path ?

Comment: @przemo_li The full path to the server? `http://localhost/afton/internalPages/index.php?action=deleteEntry`. I just tried that and got the same error

Comment: Then that url is incorrect (if it's 404) or web server is misconfigured (if it's 403).

Comment: @przemo_li Well, when I've gotten 403s in the past with this development server, it meant there was an issue with the AJAX call and the url is not incorrect, because I can take that one posted above, put it in my browser and reach that place

Comment: Wait, you said you had same error and now you say it worked... I'm confused.

Comment: @Salketer Well, I can get to the physical location if I paste that url into my browser bar, but it doesn't accomplish it because I need the variables passed in order to delete the row from the DB.

Comment: replace `window.location = ajax.responseText.trim();` with `alert(ajax.responseText.trim())` please, and let us know what it does.

Comment: @przemo_li please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Seems like I guessed wrong... According to newer comments.

Looking at your PHP you have something like `echo "/afton/internalPages/index.php?action=$location";}` and `echo "/afton/index.php?action=$location";` that makes me assume the pages are served at `http://localhost/afton/`

The problem is that on your ajax, you are trying to reach `../internalPages/index.php?action=deleteEntry` the ../ will make the browser move up one directory level, so if the page is served at `http://localhost/afton/`, it will translate to `http://localhost/internalPages/index.php?action=deleteEntry`.

You got 2 options, just remove the `../` or keep using absolute URLs like in your PHP, that would give `/afton/internalPages/index.php?action=deleteEntry`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought it was too, then I tried that path and got the same result, although further in the URL, it says this as well:`<h2>Error 404</h2><address>  <a href="/">localhost</a>`

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone needs a good humbling.......it was me. I had the directory "internalPages" spelled "interalPages" on my server. You were all right, feel free to use all the I told-you-sos that you would like.